# Return 20 if formula value is higher than 20 else return formula value

Tags: sql, netsuite, saved-searches

I have the below formula. If the result is greater than 20 I want it to return 20 else return the value from the formula.

```
CASE WHEN {memberitem.inventorylocation} = ‘Warehouse 1’ AND {type} = ‘Kit/Package’ THEN {memberitem.locationquantityavailable} WHEN {inventorylocation} = ‘Warehouse 1’ THEN {locationquantityavailable} END
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to nest `CASE` statements, so something like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN {your entire formula} > 20 then 20
    ELSE {your entire formula}
END
```